# Windows 8 tablet command prompt borderless fullscreen mode

Tags: windows-8, command-line, tablet, fullscreen

My project is processing a big queue of devices and I want to use a windows 8 tablet that is not in use anymore to display the status of the queue with a *Python* script. The script is running fine and the tablet has no problem of keeping up with it.

What I do not like is, that I have the usual window borders around the command prompt, as I would prefer running the application in fullscreen.
Usually you can achieve this by hitting `F11` on your keyboard, but sadly this won't work for me, as I do not have a keyboard for the tablet.

I have tried using the virtual keyboard to hit `F11`, which does not work (not showing any reaction/no difference) and found no other solutions on the internet.

How do I manually or programatically set the command prompt to a borderless fullscreen window?

Comment: [How to Fix Full Screen Command Prompt](http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-Full-Screen-Command-Prompt) gives 3 different options. One of them may work for you.

Comment: None of them helps, sadly @DavidPostill